# DriveApp.getFileById() throwing a server error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I am using to export a google sheet to a PDF. It has been working no problem up until now. I deployed it as a Web App so that it could be used by anyone. Since I deployed it, it has not worked. I tried archiving the Web App and that did not help.

The issue seems to be with the `DriveApp.getFileById()` function. I inserted numerous `console.log()` functions along the way of my code to try to narrow down where it actually fails and why. The execution log shows that the error is happening at the same spot that I derived, but the `console.log()` functions did not help me figure out why. The error I receive is:

> Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

I have tried researching this for quite some time now, and have tried suggestions that I found. I double checked all my variables and code syntax. I also know that the `pdfid` is being pulled correctly, as verified by logging it. I have not altered this part of the code, or any part that it depends on, at all since it has been working. I believe the Web App deployment is the issue, but I'm not sure why or how I could fix it. It could also be something else I'm missing, as it still does not work even after archiving the Web App.

Here is the code, the last line shown is where it fails:

```js
function exportLog(type) {
  console.log('Starting Export');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var realExp = sheet.getSheetByName('exportThis');
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  //console.log('Spreadsheet created');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var sheet = realExp.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
  //console.log('Copied');

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Beginning export...','Loading...',-1);
  //console.log('using new sheet');
newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of exportThis').showSheet();
  //console.log('successfully used new sheet');
newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  //console.log('deleted');
var pdfid = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  console.log(pdfid); // Correctly logs ID
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfid);
```

Comment: @JasonE. I was not able to find that while researching, I must not have used the right words, thank you for pointing me to that!

Comment: @JasonE. Yes, that solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function exportLog(type) {
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//this returns the active spreadsheet
  const xsh = ss1.getSheetByName('exportThis');
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  const nsh = xsh.copyTo(ss2);
  nsh.showSheet();//you can't really show the sheet because ss2 is not the active spreadsheet
  ss2.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();//again you can't activate this sheet because ss2 is not the active spreadsheet
  ss2.deleteActiveSheet();//This is not the active spreadsheet
  const pdfid = ss2.getId();//I don't know why you call this a pdf it's a spreadsheet
  const pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfid); //again ss2 is a newly created spreadsheet
}

//Input parameter is never used
```

You should get in the habit of referring to the documentation while you write your code and pay special attention to the types that are returned by methods.

Comment: Thanks for the cleaned up code! A lot of what I used what just copied from another source from when I was first learning everything, and I just haven't rewritten it. Also there is more to the code that was not relevant for my question, so the input parameter is eventually used.